# How to prove that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{k+1} = 2^{n+1} - 1$ using the Binomial Theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have this proposition:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{k+1} = 2^{n+1} - 1$$

How can I prove that? How to use the Binomial Theorem to solve that?

Comment: Write $2^{n+1}=(1+1)^{n+1}$

Comment: But what about the $-1$ in the end? I need to do some kind of manipulation on the binomial. The original proposition is

Comment: Hint: Can you prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{i} = 2^{n+1} - 1\ ?$$

Comment: The original proposition is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{1+k} \binom{n}{k} = \frac{2^{n+1} - 1}{n+1}$$
but I've managed to get rid of the $\frac{1}{1+k}$ by replacing the original binomial with $\frac{1}{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k+1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}-1\tag{2}\\
> &=(1+1)^{n+1}-1\tag{3}\\
> &=2^{n+1}-1
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index of the sum by one to start from $k=1$.
- In (2) we add the summand with index $k=0$ and subtract $1$ correspondingly.
- In (3) we apply the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Both sides count the number of subset of a set with $n+1$ elements, minus the empty set. Also, the formula could be rewritten as:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\matrix{n\\k}\right) = 2^n -1$$

Answer (score 0):

Use inductive approach

**For n = 0**: $$\binom{1}{1} = 1 = 2^1 - 1$$ => TRUE

**Assume that for n>=0, the following (*) is true** $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{k+1} = 2^{n+1} - 1$$

**We need prove**: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+2}{k+1} = 2^{n+2} - 1$$

Remember: $$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
So: $$\binom{n+2}{k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k+1} + \binom{n+1}{k}$$

=> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+2}{k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}$$
$$=\binom{n+1}{n+2} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1} - \binom{n+1}{0}$$

$$=2*\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1} - 1 = 2*2^{n+1} - 1 = 2^{n+2}-1$$

That is what to be proven.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{k+1} = 2^{n+1} - 1$

Solution:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k+1} + \binom{n}{0}$

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k+1} +1$

therefrore,

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k+1} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} -1  $

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k+1} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} -1  $ .....(1)

we know,

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^{n} $

so,

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} = 2^{n+1} $

finally (1) can be written as...

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k+1} =2^{n+1} -1  $